# Submodular optimization over independent set

Tags: graph-theory, combinatorial-optimization

Given a graph $G=(V,E)$ and a submodular function $F:2^V\rightarrow[0,1]$, we seek an independent set $S$ of $G$ that maximizes $F(S)$. Is there any approximation algorithm solving this submodular optimization problem?

To make the problem more explicit, consider the following example: assume that each vertex $v$ has a number of colors. We seek an independent set to maximize the total number of colors. As an extension, each color can have a weight, and we seek to maximize the weighted sum.

Comment: This question is phrased in such a way that---as far as the **worst case** is concerned---*the submodular function is* **irrelevant**. Reason: a *constant* function on $2^V$ is submodular, and for such a function, any independent set "maximizes $F(S)$. Therefore, *you are simply asking 'is  there any approximationi algorithm solving the maximum independent set problem?*. This is a much-studied problem. A nice introductory survey is [ Magnús M. Halldórsson, *Approximations of Independet Sets in Graphs*,APPROX 1998: Approximation Algorithms for Combinatiorial Optimization].

Comment: @PeterHeinig. Thank you for your comments. I don't quite understand your comment "any IS maximizes $F(s)$". Let me reformulate the problem. Let $I$ denote the set of ISs, my problem is $max_{S\in I} F(S)$. If $F(S)=\sum_{t\in S}w_t$, then the problem degenerates to the max weight IS problem. In my problem, $F(\cdot)$ is submodular.

Comment: Re 2018-03-29 08:13:58Z: I am sorry, my comment did not quite make sense. I was writing hurriedly, and was conflating constant functions on $2^V$ with constant functions on $V$. However, the *non*-constant function on $2^V$ defined by the latter in the natural way is submodular too, and it was this what I meant and this does make sense: if $F\colon 2^V\to[0,1]$ is the *cardinality* function, then $F$ is submodular, and maximizing $F$ over the independent sets means finding a maximum independent set. Hence, you are requesting an algorithm which is *at least as powerful* as a maximum i.s. alg.

Comment: @PeterHeinig. Thank you Peter. Let me give an example. Assume that each vertex $v$ has a number of colors. We seek an IS to maximize the total number of colors. As an extension, each color can have a weight, and we seek to maximize the weighted sum.